# Group of Dirichlet Characters Modulo $q$ is Isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z} / q\mathbb{Z})^*$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm currently reading a book on analytic number theory, and shortly after defining Dirichlet characters, the author stated that one can prove that for a given $q\in\mathbb{N}$, the group of Dirichlet characters modulo $q$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z} / q \mathbb{Z})^*$. That sparked my interest, so I started to think about how to prove this fact, but unfortunately I've had no success and have been unable to find a proof elsewhere. Can somebody please shed some light on how to prove this fact?

In case it's relevant, here's the definition of Dirichlet characters provided by my book:

Let $q \in \mathbb{N}$. A Dirichlet character modulo $q$ is a map $\chi : \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfying the following rules for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$:

1. $\chi(a) = \chi(a \pmod q)$
2. $\chi(ab) = \chi(a)\chi(b)$
3. If $(a, q)>1$, then $\chi(a)=0$.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The neutral element is the unique character of period 1  the trivial or principal character $(mod q)$. this character sends all integers relatively prime to $q$ to $1$ and the rest to $0$, the proof can be separated in two  steps, first we prove the result for primes and then generalize it to powers of primes and composite numbers

Comment: @Elaqqad Thank you for your response. I understand what you're saying about the identity element of the group of characters modulo $q$. However, I'm still unsure on how to write an actual proof. I tried proving it when $q$ is prime and still got stuck. Can you possibly give a bit more information, please?

Comment: @Gecko I'm working on writing some things up myself; would you like me to submit my mostly expository (for now) answer early? I'm by no means an expert, but it might be helpful to you.

Comment: @pjs36 If you could do so that would be excellent. Thank you. With any luck it'll be enough to get me going in the correct direction.

Comment: One of the difficulties here is that there is no _canonical_ isomorphism of a finite abelian group with its _dual_... So there's no innate formulaic approach... which is why you can't find one. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a Dirichlet character, so this is an adventure for me too! Maybe my thought process will help out.

> Let $q \in \mathbb{N}$. A Dirichlet character modulo $q$ is a map $\chi : \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfying the following rules for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$:
>
> 1. $\chi(a) = \chi(a \pmod q)$
> 2. $\chi(ab) = \chi(a)\chi(b)$
> 3. If $(a, q)>1$, then $\chi(a)=0$.

Let $G = \Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z$, so that $G^* = (\Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z)^*$.

Let's pick apart the definition for a bit. By requiring $\chi(a) = \chi(a \pmod q)$, we're really forcing $\chi$ to be defined not just on $\Bbb Z$, but on $G$ as well. For $a \in \Bbb Z$, let $[a]$ denote the equivalence class $\{n \in \Bbb Z: n \equiv a \pmod q\}$. Now it shouldn't be hard to believe that, given a function $\chi : G \to \Bbb C$ satisfying criteria 2. and 3., that it can be extended to a function $\chi: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb C$ by criteria 1; that is, making it periodic, modulo $q$.

Now let's look more closely at criterion 2. We already mentioned that we can view $\chi$ as a function $G \to \Bbb C$, could we also view it as a function $\chi: G^* \to \Bbb C$? Of course! And it turns out that not only is $\chi : G^* \to \Bbb C$ a *function*, it's a function that makes groups happy: A homomorphism! This is exactly what criterion 2 forces; we have $$\chi([ab]) = \chi([a][b]) = \chi([a])\chi([b]).$$

Now that we have a homomorphism, all sorts of wonderful things happen. For example, we know that $\chi$ only maps things to complex roots of unity. This is because the size of $G^*$ is $n = \phi(q)$, Euler's totient function. For $[a] \in G^*$, we have $[a]^n = [1]$, and since $\chi$ is a homomorphism, we have $$1 = \chi([1]) = \chi([a]^n) = \chi([a])^n = 1;$$ in particular, $\chi([a])$ is an $n$th root of unity.

Let $\hat{G^*}$ be the set of characters $G^*: \to \Bbb C$. The big question question is: How do we multiply characters $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$?

One sensible choice would be to define \begin{align*}
\chi_1\chi_2: \Bbb G^* &\to \Bbb C\\
[a] &\mapsto \chi_1([a])\chi_2([a]).
\end{align*}

It seems reasonable that the character

\begin{align*}\hat{1}: G^* &\to \Bbb C\\ [a] &\mapsto 1\end{align*} would act as the identity character, and you can verify that it does.

We can define inverse characters pointwise; given $\chi \in \hat{G}^*$, we define $\chi^{-1}([a]) := (\chi([a]))^{-1} = \chi([a]^{-1})$.

Unfortunately, this is about as far as I've made it; but here's a reference to help you forward: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/charthy.pdf

These notes by K. Conrad have the theorem that we need, and it's theorem 3.12: That an abelian group is isomorphic to it's dual. I realize I've left only scattered and disjointed breadcrumbs, and stopped short of the main course! But hopefully the group of characters is slightly less mysterious.

Comment: I should say, we've secretly been working in the geoup that's dual to $G^*$; thats why Conrad's theorems are at all helpful. But hopefully after a little time and sleep, this can all be made perfectly clear!

Comment: Thank you for all of your information! You've helped me get a better grasp on the Dirichlet characters, and I think I'm on the right track to prove the statement when $q$ is an odd prime. If I come up with a full proof I'll be sure to post it here for future readers.